# How to embed fancytree in a drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fancytree

I'm using the fancytree jQuery plugin to select one item from a list of 635 in 21 categories. Great tool, lazy loading and persistence are especially useful to my application. But... I'm out of real estate on my window.

How can I embed a fancytree in a drop down of some sort, jQuery-UI preferably as I'm already loading that for other needs. I can afford a fraction of one line for the drop down to save an entire column for the fancytree.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about this plugin? https://github.com/mar10/fancytree

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Thanks, Bill.

Comment: Anyone knows the answer for this.. i am looking for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I had to do it my self without plugs-in or extension as the following:

I needed to show the user the selected tree branch and to store the node key in a hidden input, also I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap but feel free to change it you wish.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Location</label>
    <input id="myLocation" type="hidden" />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span id="myLocation" class="form-control"></span>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary tree-opener" data-target="#myFancyTreeID" type="button">...</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myFancyTreeID" class="form-control" data-target="#myLocation" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function () {
    $('.tree-opener').on('click', function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).slideToggle();
    });

    $('#myFancyTreeID').fancytree({
        activate: function (event, data) {
            var node = data.node;
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(node.key)) {
                var $displayControl = $('span' + $tree.data('target'));
                var $valueControl = $('input' + $tree.data('target'));
                $displayControl.html(node.title);
                $valueControl.val(node.key);
                $tree.slideToggle();
            }
        },
        source: { /* …. your data source …. */ }
    });
});
```

This is a starter code and you can re-code it the way that suits your page.